# Should I comment to help prevent "downvote-bombing"?

Tags: discussion

I recently [suggested an edited](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/167433) to the question [Why is Software Updater showing additional updates?](https://askubuntu.com/q/355970/107590), but because the OP hasn't accepted the edit, his post still looks like garbage to all other AskUbuntu users. As such, his question is getting "downvote-bombed" (couldn't think of a better term for it), and is at risk of being deleted purely for being formatted poorly (although, I would argue that it's too broad/vague to answer).

Should I comment, mentioning that I have formatted the question to make it understandable, so as to try and prevent the barrage of downvotes?

Comment: I don't think adding a comment would help much. Edits usually go through the queue much faster than this one did. I have removed my downvote now that the question has become a question. Thanks for your edit! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, you don't need to do that.

Doing so doesn't really help much, as edits usually end up going through the edits review queue a ton faster than you'd expect.  Downvoters who downvote a question because it's not a question are the ones who will need to go and remove their downvote after an edit is approved, but they might not get to it in time.

Creating a comment just to ward off downvoters doesn't really add anything, except noise, to the question and its comments.